# Why is Furuya's grandfather called "Professor Boil"?

Tags: sankarea

In the manga, Darin and later Darin's father (Chief of Zoma) keeps referring to Furuya's grandfather as "Professor Boil". Is there a reason behind his name?

Below are some examples:

- Chapter 10 (Darin):

  [image: Chapter 10 - Darin]
- Chapter 31 (Darin's father - Chief of Zoma):

  [image: Chapter 31 - Darin's father]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the same page of chapter 10 in the original Japanese version.

Furuya's grandfather's full name is 降谷 茹五郎 (Furuya Jogorou), and his nickname "Professor Boil" comes from the character 茹 in his name, since 茹でる means "to boil".

[image: Chapter 10]